# delegate use in sencha touch 6

Tags: html, extjs, web, sencha-touch

### Good morning Folks!

If you have a sencha FieldSet and has many fields, you can delegate an event to his sons:

```
fieldset.on({
        change: 'ChangeFieldValue',
        delegate: 'field',
        scope: me
    });
```

Also, I haven't find good documentation about delegate events. If anybody know about it please let me know.

Working with:
*Sencha 6.0.2.14*

#### free knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

A simple selector to filter the event target or look for a descendant of the target.
The "delegate" option is only available on Ext.dom.Element instances (or when attaching a listener to a Ext.dom.Element via a Component using the element option).
This is a configuration option that you can pass along when registering a handler for an event to assist with event delegation. By setting this configuration option to a simple selector, the target element will be filtered to look for a descendant of the target.
See the delegate example below.

```
var panel = Ext.create({
xtype: 'panel',
renderTo: document.body,
title: 'Delegate Handler Example',
frame: true,
height: 220,
width: 220,
html: '<h1 class="myTitle">BODY TITLE</h1>Body content'
});

// The click handler will only be called when the click occurs on the
// delegate: h1.myTitle ("h1" tag with class "myTitle")
panel.on({
    click: function (e) {
        console.log(e.getTarget().innerHTML);
    },
    element: 'body',
    delegate: 'h1.myTitle'
 });
```